# Importance of SSL Encryption

Tags: ssl, encryption, jira

I have heard that it is important to utilize an SSL certificate to web traffic.  I have read that without an SSL, there is the possibility that usernames, password and other information could be intercepted by intermediaries between my computer (i.e. the client) and the ISP.

My question is: what exactly does that mean?  Would someone have to in my network in order to intercept this information?  How much of a danger is it?  If I have web servers set up for the use of small groups (such as my JIRA server), how likely is it that it will get hacked by someone seeing username/password combos?

And if it is so important, why is SSL security not always a core aspect of these servers?  For instance, JIRA does not support SSL (although they have [resources](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Running+JIRA+over+SSL+or+HTTPS) to help you figure it out on your own).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about network security. security.SE would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without ssl or equivalent encryption, anybody between you and the server can read the traffic. These are called man in the middle attacks. However, attackers can also just listen to networks and watch the packets go by ( see tools like wireshark ).  So, if you are using open wifi, or weakly protected wifi, or if an attacker can plug onto you ethernet segment, ( or your telco ) then they can sniff your data.  Overall fairly simple for a person with motivation.

Why dont all servers include this?

1. It requires more coding effort
2. Importance is not always understood
3. There is a old belief that it affects performance (not really true any more)
4. (advanced/weird). Ssl link setup requires multiple trips, which can be slow over some very slow networks

Comment: So for a man-in-the-middle attack, do the attackers have to be able to have access to your network specifically in order to use a tool like wireshark? What part of the telco would they have to plug into? I think that the biggest concern that I have is with people remotely seeing traffic - is there a way for them to hack into my network outside of brute-forcing there way into a VPN that would give them access to my ethernet?

Comment: Basically need access to network, but depends on level of skill and budget ( eg see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_(codename) ). As advised, jump over to security.se, but try not to get too paranoid! Eg http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32181/how-risky-is-it-not-to-install-ssl/32207#32207